# Validate that all characters in a user input are a part of pre-approved list of characters

Tags: python, loops, validation, input, iteration

In my python code, I am trying to validate whether all characters of a user input fall into a list of approved characters. I am using a for loop within a while loop, thinking that the for loop will check that the characters of the user's input fall into the list of approved characters, and the while loop will prompt a new input from the user every time they use a character that is not included in the approved list.

```
approved_characters = ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S",
"T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "'", "-", ".", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n",
"o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z")

# fist name input, validated to ensure only approved characters
while True:
    first = input("First name: ")
    for i in range(0, len(first)):
        if first[i] in approved_characters:
            pass
        else:
            print("Only use approved characters (A-Z/,/./-/')")
        break
```

Comment: Where is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to community,
What is exactly your problem?
Some comments on your code:

- you can use  `string.ascii_lowercase` instead of list alphabets manually, but make sure to `import string`
- just use: `for c in first: if c in approved chars`, no need the index, strings in python are also considered as list of chars